# Segmented Control on Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I am adding a segmented control inside my view controller.My viewdidLoad is as follow

```
 self.navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Image", @""),
                                                                                   NSLocalizedString(@"Text", @""), nil]];
[segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:0];
[segmentedControl setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 30);
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;
[segmentedControl release]; 

[self.view addSubview:self.navController.view];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

Only the navigation bar keeps on coming without any segmented control inside it.
Can someone help and let me know what exactly is wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your navigation controller is starting out with no root view controller—you're setting the segmented control as your view controller’s title view correctly, but you’re not giving the navigation controller a reference to that view controller. You need to initialize it like this:

```
self.navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self] autorelease];
```

Comment: I am getting “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” when I try to do so.basically I have tab bar as my main controller and inside one of the tabs I am trying to have segmented control on navigation bar.Is there something else I need to do to get this work properly.

Comment: There's a sort of nesting order to set up. You put your view controller “inside” the navigation controller—as its root view controller—and then add the navigation controller to the tab bar controller. Then all you need to hold on to a reference to is your own view controller and the tab bar controller.